# Excel keeps freezing

Tags: excel, crash

I have a large workbook with a lot of links between cells, it started crashing a lot last week. I made a not to clean the file and did not think much of it. However the problem seems to have transferred to the excel as a hole and even, transferred the issue to another user in my company who I sent the original file too.

Can anyone suggest the best coarse of action to fix this issue completely. I was going to clean the file, then contact IT in my company to reinstall office.

Thanks

Stephen

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft released an untested update this morning and subsequently released a patch an hour later.